# Plotting respecting the x-axis values scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I generate the following plot:

[image]

By the following code:

```
data = {'BestFit_rej_ratio': {0: 0.1975987994, 1: 0.2006003002, 2: 0.1790895448, 3: 0.2216108054, 4: 0.1785892946, 5: 0.1890945473, 6: 0.1780890445, 7: 0.1780890445, 8: 0.2016008004, 9: 0.1900950475, 10: 0.1985992996, 11: 0.2031015508, 12: 0.2046023012, 13: 0.2071035518, 14: 0.1750875438, 15: 0.2166083042, 16: 0.1725862931, 17: 0.188094047, 18: 0.1870935468, 19: 0.1895947974, 20: 0.004502251126, 21: 0.006503251626, 22: 0.005002501251, 23: 0.006503251626, 24: 0.008004002001, 25: 0.006003001501, 26: 0.00300150075, 27: 0.005502751376, 28: 0.0100050025, 29: 0.005002501251, 30: 0.006003001501, 31: 0.005502751376, 32: 0.007503751876, 33: 0.005502751376, 34: 0.005502751376, 35: 0.005502751376, 36: 0.007503751876, 37: 0.005002501251, 38: 0.004002001001, 39: 0.009004502251, 40: 0.4172086043, 41: 0.4322161081, 42: 0.4017008504, 43: 0.4247123562, 44: 0.4292146073, 45: 0.4077038519, 46: 0.4282141071, 47: 0.4637318659, 48: 0.4392196098, 49: 0.4172086043, 50: 0.4187093547, 51: 0.4057028514, 52: 0.4287143572, 53: 0.4242121061, 54: 0.4347173587, 55: 0.4307153577, 56: 0.4102051026, 57: 0.4437218609, 58: 0.4212106053, 59: 0.4172086043}, 'MDP_rej_ratio': {0: 0.1660830415, 1: 0.1605802901, 2: 0.152076038, 3: 0.1885942971, 4: 0.152076038, 5: 0.1565782891, 6: 0.1445722861, 7: 0.1570785393, 8: 0.1705852926, 9: 0.1605802901, 10: 0.1740870435, 11: 0.1670835418, 12: 0.1805902951, 13: 0.1740870435, 14: 0.1460730365, 15: 0.1810905453, 16: 0.1425712856, 17: 0.1580790395, 18: 0.1455727864, 19: 0.1590795398, 20: 0.001500750375, 21: 0.00300150075, 22: 0.002501250625, 23: 0.002501250625, 24: 0.0020010005, 25: 0.002501250625, 26: 0.0020010005, 27: 0.001500750375, 28: 0.004002001001, 29: 0.00300150075, 30: 0.0020010005, 31: 0.0, 32: 0.004002001001, 33: 0.0005002501251, 34: 0.0020010005, 35: 0.0, 36: 0.004502251126, 37: 0.002501250625, 38: 0.001500750375, 39: 0.004002001001, 40: 0.3851925963, 41: 0.3851925963, 42: 0.4097048524, 43: 0.3756878439, 44: 0.4112056028, 45: 0.4212106053, 46: 0.3791895948, 47: 0.4127063532, 48: 0.4432216108, 49: 0.4152076038, 50: 0.3871935968, 51: 0.4197098549, 52: 0.3896948474, 53: 0.4107053527, 54: 0.4062031016, 55: 0.4252126063, 56: 0.4112056028, 57: 0.3931965983, 58: 0.4372186093, 59: 0.4157078539}, 'Q-Learning_rej_ratio': {0: 0.1790895448, 1: 0.1645822911, 2: 0.1545772886, 3: 0.1905952976, 4: 0.1510755378, 5: 0.1595797899, 6: 0.148074037, 7: 0.1575787894, 8: 0.1715857929, 9: 0.1590795398, 10: 0.1690845423, 11: 0.168084042, 12: 0.180090045, 13: 0.1785892946, 14: 0.1495747874, 15: 0.1815907954, 16: 0.1435717859, 17: 0.1685842921, 18: 0.1505752876, 19: 0.1670835418, 20: 0.001500750375, 21: 0.00300150075, 22: 0.002501250625, 23: 0.002501250625, 24: 0.0020010005, 25: 0.002501250625, 26: 0.0020010005, 27: 0.001500750375, 28: 0.004002001001, 29: 0.00300150075, 30: 0.0020010005, 31: 0.0, 32: 0.004002001001, 33: 0.0005002501251, 34: 0.0020010005, 35: 0.0, 36: 0.004502251126, 37: 0.002501250625, 38: 0.001500750375, 39: 0.004002001001, 40: 0.3856928464, 41: 0.4167083542, 42: 0.3786893447, 43: 0.4187093547, 44: 0.4157078539, 45: 0.392196098, 46: 0.4032016008, 47: 0.4452226113, 48: 0.4217108554, 49: 0.3876938469, 50: 0.4192096048, 51: 0.388194097, 52: 0.4122061031, 53: 0.4152076038, 54: 0.4172086043, 55: 0.4137068534, 56: 0.3956978489, 57: 0.4342171086, 58: 0.4082041021, 59: 0.4032016008}, 'Parametrized_factor': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 8: 1.0, 9: 1.0, 10: 1.0, 11: 1.0, 12: 1.0, 13: 1.0, 14: 1.0, 15: 1.0, 16: 1.0, 17: 1.0, 18: 1.0, 19: 1.0, 20: 0.2, 21: 0.2, 22: 0.2, 23: 0.2, 24: 0.2, 25: 0.2, 26: 0.2, 27: 0.2, 28: 0.2, 29: 0.2, 30: 0.2, 31: 0.2, 32: 0.2, 33: 0.2, 34: 0.2, 35: 0.2, 36: 0.2, 37: 0.2, 38: 0.2, 39: 0.2, 40: 2.0, 41: 2.0, 42: 2.0, 43: 2.0, 44: 2.0, 45: 2.0, 46: 2.0, 47: 2.0, 48: 2.0, 49: 2.0, 50: 2.0, 51: 2.0, 52: 2.0, 53: 2.0, 54: 2.0, 55: 2.0, 56: 2.0, 57: 2.0, 58: 2.0, 59: 2.0}}


data2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

ax = sns.pointplot(y="BestFit_rej_ratio", x="Parametrized_factor",   data=data2, linestyles='-.', color='g', capsize=.1, scale=.2,  errwidth=.5)
ax = sns.pointplot(y="MDP_rej_ratio", x="Parametrized_factor",   data=data2, linestyles='-',  color='r', capsize=.12, scale=.2, errwidth=.5)
ax = sns.pointplot(y="Q-Learning_rej_ratio", x="Parametrized_factor",   data=data2, linestyles=':',  color='k', capsize=.15, scale=.5, errwidth=.5)


ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.15, 1), loc='upper left')

labels = ax.legend(['BestFit', 'MDP', 'Q-Learning'])
colors = ['green', 'red', 'black']
i = 0
for l in labels.get_texts():
    l.set_color(colors[i])
    i+=1

 plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='12') 
# for legend text

ax.set_ylabel('Rejection ratio')    
ax.set_xlabel('Parametrized factor')

plt.show()
```

Problem is that the plot is not respecting the scale of the x-axis values (Parametrized_factor).

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you want a non-categorical x-axis for a `pointplot`, the official recommendation is to use `lmplot` instead.  See [this github issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/305).

Comment: Thanks for the info @JohanC I’ll have a look.